# Laravel 4.2 in FTP server throwing Error 500

Tags: laravel, ftp, autoload, filezilla

I've searched everywhere for a solution. Plus, I tried tracking the error using `echo("teste");`, but can't find exactly what is wrong, since it works on my local host.

From `index.php` -> `bootstrap/autoload.php` -> `vender/autoload.php`:

I could print a msg until before the `foreach` in `getLoader` method of `ComposerAutoloaderInitxxxxxx` class.

I see it can't complete the require in both `bootstrap/autoload.php` or `bootstrap/start.php`

my directories levels are:

```
public_html/
|__laravel/
   |__app/
   |__bootstrap/
   |__vender/
   |__index.php
   |__artisan
   |__robots.txt
```

I've changed the paths correctly when moved the files from `public/` to laravel root, since I can get into the files required (it just can't finish loading).

I get

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

Ps.: I uploaded the project through Filezilla, and I only have the FTP access.

Please, could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok first you should not upload a Laravel project via FTP, if you only have an FTP access then you need a real hosting provider that has SSH. You should be able to use the `composer` command on your production server or you will be in big trouble later :)

Also, assuming this is a cPanel host (based on the `public_html` folder) the proper way would be to `git clone` the Laravel project under a folder, remove the `public_html` folder and create a symbolic link like this.

```
ln -s ~/laravel/public ~/public_html
```

This way your document root will point to Laravel's public folder.

Here is more information:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-install-laravel-in-the-root-directory

Comment: I read about some people who uploaded the project via Filezilla and said it worked with a few changes (like running composer update in their local host, then throwing on the server).

So, are you telling me there is no way that method could be right? Problem is that I can't remove public_html, I share this folder with other developers.

Then there is a way I can access this host only with ftp credentials? I am not that familiar with server managment, sorry my ignorance.

Thanks for the tips, Pascal. ;)